# How can I get Google Assistant to talk to "TickTick" instead of "Tik tik"?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I use a todo list app called TickTick. The app has a Google Assistant integration [available](https://blog.ticktick.com/post/189516482614/lets-talk-on-google-assistant). However, when I try to say "Talk to TickTick" Google Assistant always talks to another quiz app called "Tik Tik" instead.

Is there some way I can fix Google Assistant to talk to TickTick todo list app instead of this other quiz app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a "Routine" in the Google Assistant settings such that:

- When I say "notepad or "note pad"
- Assistant will: "Talk to ticktick"

Now, all I have to say is: "Okay Google. Notepad"

Answer (score 2):

Try asking *"Speak to TickTick"* instead.

It looks like [TickTick](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000554705b031) reacts to multiple invocations such as the above, whereas the clashing [Tik Tik](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000608075b3cf) action only reacts to *"Talk to Tik Tik"*.

Ideally one or the other would change the action name to avoid the clash, but hopefully this workaround solves it for now.